# The intersection of a sphere and the xy-plane is the circle $(x-1)^2+(y-2)^2=5$ and point $(1,2,1)$ is on the sphere

Tags: multivariable-calculus

The intersection of a sphere and the $xy$-plane is the circle $$(x-1)^2+(y-2)^2=5$$ and point $(1,2,1)$ is on the sphere. Find the center and radius of the sphere.

When the sphere and $xy$-plane intersect than $z=0$. 
I tried $(x-1)^2+(y-2)^2+(z+?)^2=5$ but what can I do next?

Answer (score 3):

**Hint** Note that the point $(1,2,1)$ is directly above the center of the circle. This means it is the *top* of the sphere. The center of the sphere is therefore a point $(1,2,a)$ equidistant from the points of the circle and the point $(1,2,1).$

Comment: thank you for the answering but I still don't get it. So why equidistant from the point (1,2,1) is the hint?

Comment: What is the distance from $(1,2,a)$ to the points of the circle? What is the distance from $(1,2,a)$ to $(1,2,1)$?

Comment: Remember that they are points on a sphere, all of which are equidistant from the sphere's center.

Answer (score 1):

Just put $(x,y,z)=(1,2,1)$ in the equation $(x-1)^{2}+(y-2)^{2}+(z-c)^{2}=c^{2}+5$. You get $(1-c)^{2}=5$ so $c=-2$. The center is $(1,2,-2)$ and radius is $\sqrt 9=3$.

Comment: Yes, I don't really don't know how I switched to a new answer. I must have hit something accidentally. Apologies.

Comment: @cyan You need $c^{2}+5$ on the right side and not just $5$. This because when $z=0$ the equation must reduce to the given equation in $(x,y)$.

Comment: I got the idea of it  thank you so much and I would like to ask you how can I know the radius in this sphere with center and equation in here.

Comment: @cyan My starting point is that the equation of the sphere has to be of the form $(x-a)^{2}+(y-b)^{2}+(z-c)^{2}=R^{2}$, where $R$ is the radius and $(a,b,c)$ is the center. The next step is to note that if we put $z=0$ the equation must reduce to the given equation. In the final step I use the fact that $x=1,y=2,z=1$ must satisfy the equation. If you use these steps you will get $R^{2}=9, a=1,b=2$ and $c =-2$.

Comment: thank you for answering again now I got this!!

Answer (score 1):

Hint: take any point $A$ on that circle and calculate the plane which perpendicular bisector of segment $AB$ where $B=(1,2,1)$. Point where this plane cuts line $(1,2,z)$ is center.

Answer (score 1):

Let $O(a,b,c)$ be center of sphere, $A(1,2,0)$ be the center of intersection circle, $B(1,2+\sqrt{5},0)$ be the point of the sphere and intersection circle, $C(1,2,1)$ be the point on the sphere.

Then the radius of the sphere is $R=OC=OB=AO+AC=AO+1$.

The triangle $AOB$ is right, so:
$$AO^2+AB^2=OB^2 \Rightarrow AO^2+5=(AO+1)^2 \Rightarrow AO=2.$$
Thus:
$$R=AO+1=3;O(1,2,-2).$$

Answer (score 0):

One more :

Equation of the sphere:

$(x-a)^2+(y-b)^2+(z-c)^2=R^2.$

Cut with plane $z=0:$

$(x-a)^2+(y-b)^2 +c^2=R^2.$

1) Compare with the given circle:

$a=1,b=2, R^2-c^2= (√5)^2$

2) $(1,2,1)$ lies on the sphere:

$0+0+(1-c)^2=R^2.$

Hence: $1-2c+c^2=R^2;$

$1-2c= R^2-c^2=(√5)^2.$

$c= (1-5)/2=-2$, and $R^2 =9$.